# VSCode custom code formatting and auto indention for language(Django-Template indention)

Tags: visual-studio-code, django-templates, vscode-extensions, code-formatting, prettier

I did a lot of search to find a away to create or override and existing extension of vscode to do indention for django-template but nothing is out there and no success in creation too.
the best answer still using this settings:

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/*.html": "html",
    "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
}
"[django-html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify",
}

"beautify.language": {
    "html": ["django-html"]
},
```

and this extensions: `Dajngo (Baptiste Darthenay)` & `beautify`. but there is no indention for django-template language and only the HTML tags will be indented. I tried to override the `Djagno` extension to make it possible, and yeah it would insert some indention but after saving the code, `Beautify` will automatically format the code and delete that indention, so the result always is like this:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %} mr-auto {% endif %}">
    {% get_available_languages as languages %}
    {% for lang_code, lang_name in languages %}
    {% if lang_code != LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    {% language lang_code %}
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link lang-setter" data-lang-code="{{ lang_code }}">
        {{ lang_code|language_name_local }}
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endlanguage %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

the ugly template.
I also provided the indention rule needed, but I couldn't find a way to force this rule for vscode code formatters like beautify or prettier.

```
  "indentationRules": {
      "increaseIndentPattern": "((\\<)(body|address|blockquote|dd|div|dl|dt|tr|tbody|thead|fieldset|form|frame|frameset|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|iframe|noframes|object|ol|p|ul|applet|center|dir|a|menu|pre|table|button|a|abbr|acronym|area|b|base|basefont|bdo|big|br|button|caption|cite|code|col|colgroup|del|dfn|em|font|head|html|i|img|input|ins|isindex|kbd|label|legend|li|link|map|meta|noscript|optgroup|option|param|q|s|samp|script|select|small|span|strike|strong|style|sub|sup|table|tbody|td|textarea|tfoot|th|thead|title|tr|tt|u|var))|(\\{\\%)\\s*(autoescape|block|blocktrans|blocktranslate|comment|for|empty|if|elif|else|ifchanged|ifequal|ifnotequal|from|low|regroup|ssi|spaceless|templatetag|widthratio|with|verbatim|thumbnail)",
      "decreaseIndentPattern": "((\\<\\/)(.*)*(\\>))|((\\{\\%)\\s*(empty|elif|else|end(autoescape|block|blocktrans|blocktranslate|comment|for|if|ifchanged|ifequal|ifnotequal|spaceless|with|verbatim|thumbnail)))"
      }
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, I found this helpful project https://github.com/Riverside-Healthcare/djlint

For install it in vscode do (I recommend to install it in a virtual environment):

```
pip install djlint
```

Once this done. I use the extension [run on save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) and add similar configuration in settings.json

```
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "match": "\\.html$",
            "isAsync": true,
            "cmd": "./path/to/venv/bin/djlint ${file} --reformat --quiet" 
        }
    ]    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now there is [djlint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=monosans.djlint)¹ [by **monosans**] available both as a package that could be installed with `pip` and also as an extension for vscode which it-self needs the [djlint](https://djlint.com/docs/getting-started/)² to be installed using pip.
it seems djlint is both a linter and formatter and could be used either ways as follows:

1- as python package:

```bash
 python -m djlint --reformat --format-css --format-js --indent 2 --quiet --profile django .
```

2- as a vscode extension:

```json
"[django-html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint",
    "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
},
"djlint.formatCss": true,
"djlint.formatJs": true,
"djlint.preserveBlankLines": true,
```

- I do use [django](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django) extension by **Baptiste Darthenay**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to set up Beautify.

I will focus my answer on formatting django templates with VSCode.

### Abstract

Use `nunjucks` instead of `django-html`.

### Detail

1. Install [Nunjucks VSCode Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=douglaszaltron.nunjucks-vscode-extensionpack).
2. At this point, `html` files are not treated as `nunjucks`. Add the following settings to `.vscode/settings.json`.

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.html": "njk"
},
```

3. Fix HTML tag completion no longer works. If you have not yet installed the [Auto Close Tag extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag), do so here and add the following additional settings.

```json
"auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
    "njk",
],
```

4. ***optional*** Finally, set the icon theme. If the [Material icon theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme) has not been installed, install it and add the following settings.

```json
"material-icon-theme.files.associations": {
    "*.html": "nunjucks",
},
```

With the above procedure, you should now be able to format and syntax highlight django templates.